# Intellij database tool: delete a row in console view has no effect in edit data view

Tags: database, intellij-idea

Running the following delete statement in console_2

[image]

has no effect on view edit data even when pressing the "reload page" button.

[image]

However the following select statement shows the expected output of an empty table:

[image]

How to synchonize the console and the edit data view?

Comment: Hello! Seems you need to enable option to "Submit changes automatically": https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/submitting-and-reverting-changes.html#submit-changes-immediately

Comment: Unfortunately that does has no effect in the synchronisation of console and data view.

Answer (score 0):

For now the only solution is to click `Reload Page` to reload data if there are any. There is a feature request on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-7305